# count the number of changes of value in an array

Tags: arrays, count

I am relatively new in R and I am working with behaviour data of an animal and I am trying to establish the number of times an individual animal change its behaviour in a given time frame (session in this case).

My dummy dataset is as:-

```
session = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
activity = c("V","F","D","F","F","W","V","R","R","S","V","U","W","V","V","V","R","R","R","R")
df = data.frame(session,activity)
```

I would like to count the number of times that the activity is changed in each session. For example, in session 1 it will be 8 times and in session 2 it will be 5 times. 
I have tried options of following other suggestion on the internet to use `rle()` but I am wondering how I can code it since in most of the cases it will be summing up different modalities in a given array.

Answer (score 0):

I found out from a friend that I had to aply the rle to the "activity" column of my df, making sure that this column is a character and not a vector `df$activity=as.character(df$activity)`
I then applied the function only to the rows of a single session for instance, the rows of session 1:

```
res<-rle(df[which(df$session==1),2])#rle() function applied to the activity column of df and to the rows of the session 1
length(res$lengths)# will give you the number of changes within a session
```

but to apply it to the big data set, I could apply it in a loop:

```
df[,2]=as.character(df[,2])# to treat session as a character
ls.session=unique(df$session)
nb.session=length(ls.session)
new.df=data.frame(ls.session,rep(0,nb.session))#create an empty data.frame where we can apply the loop
names(new.df)=c("session","nb.change")
for(i in 1:nb.session){
res.rle.sess.i=rle(df[which(df$session==ls.session[i]),2])
nb.chang.sess.i=length(res.rle.sess.i$lengths)
new.df[i,2]=nb.chang.sess.i
}
new.df
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change.f = function(x) c(FALSE, x[-1] != x[-length(x)])
aggregate(change.f(df$activity)&!change.f(df$session), by=list(df$session), FUN=sum)
```

Output:

```
  Group.1 x
1       1 7
2       2 4
```